# Disable __atomic_compare_exchange in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, berkeley-db

I am trying to build [Berkeley DB](https://github.com/berkeleydb/libdb) (libdb) using Clang on macOS. It seems that the library defines some functions that are already defined by Clang:

```
In file included from src/clib/strncmp.c:36:
In file included from buck-out/gen/db_int.h/db_int.h:1113:
In file included from src/dbinc/mutex.h:15:
In file included from src/dbinc/mutex_int.h:12:
src/dbinc/atomic.h:179:19: error: definition of builtin function           
'__atomic_compare_exchange'
static inline int __atomic_compare_exchange(
```

Is it possible to disable the built-in `__atomic_compare_exchange` so that the code compiles unchanged?

---

Note that I have tried `-fno-builtin`, but it did not fix the error.

---

My `clang --version`:

```
clang --version
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: There is a patch (haven't checked version or date): https://gist.github.com/danieldk/5700533  and a thread on the same subject: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/How-to-disable-built-in-td3934787.html